# Use pointers to create a class member

Tags: c++

I am really confused about pointers. Read some articles about them and thought i got them, but i seems i didn't. I want to create a Team "Team1" which i normally would create by Team Team1; I have the name Team1 already stored as a string from an reading input of a textfile and thought i could create this team by pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Team
{
private:
    std::string m_teamname;
};


int main()
{
    std::string wort = "team1";
    std::string* pointer;
    pointer = &wort;
    std::string wort2 = *pointer;
    std::cout << wort2;
    Team *pointer;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I got the error C2371: 'pointer' : redefinition; different basic type " which is quite selfexplaning but still i dont get why it does not work as *pointer shows to the adress where the string "team1" is stored. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with pointers, per se. You are defining the same variable twice with different types (as the error says: "pointer: redefinition").

```
std::string* pointer;
...
Team *pointer;
```

You define a variable named `pointer` with type `std::string*`, but then you try and define another variable with the same name. You'll have to rename one of them to something else.

You'd run into the same problem with any type:

```
int x;
double x; // <- error: there's already an x
```

Comment: Okay, stupid me this is quite logical ;) So i need to create a team x and use the pointer to set the class member name of this team x to team1 ?

Comment: I can't quite understand what you are asking there; but `Team *teamptr = new Team()`, or `Team team; Team *teamptr = &team;` would both be valid. If you are confused about pointers in general, I highly suggest the best explanation of pointers ever: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i49_SNt4yfk (source: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/) -- Watch it completely before you judge it! Binky's been teaching us about pointers for a solid 15+ years now.

Comment: Currently, you can't set `m_teamname` from anywhere other than a member function of `class Team` - that's because of the `private:` access specifier.  If you made it `public`, then you could say `Team x; x.m_teamname = *pointer;`.  You'd normally want some member function to set the private team name though - ideally the constructor would accept a team name as an argument and store it in `m_teamname` - `Teamname(const std::string& teamname) : m_teamname(teamname) { }`.

Comment: thx i added this constructor and tried to create a team by Team a("team1"); but i got the errors "Team::Team(const std::string &teamname) ansd "Team::Team' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Team'. Seems there is still something about m_teamname being private

Comment: @jimbo999 If you cannot get your private/constructor issues worked out, feel free to post a new question about it (rather than changing this question to be a new one).